# Roslyn code fix C# - How to disable 'Document', 'Project', 'Solution' level updates in preview

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I have implemented roslyn fix without preview as per suggestions in [Roslyn analyser code fix - Disable preview option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435740/roslyn-analyser-code-fix-disable-preview-option)

However would like to know if I can disable the 'Document' 'Project' and 'Solution' options presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those options are there because you have a FixAllProvider, probably something like

```
public override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider() => WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;
```

Remove that, and those options are gone.