# Move to Resource refactoring

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, resx, vsix

I'm trying to make my own **Move to Resource** refactoring (like the one found in ReSharper). In my `CodeAction.GetChangedDocumentAsync` method I'm doing these 3 steps:

1. Add my resource to the Resources.resx file with `XmlDocument`
2. Use DTE to run the custom tool to update the Resources.Designer.cs file
3. Replace the literal string by the qualified identifier of the new resource with `SyntaxNode.ReplaceNode`

Steps 1 & 2 are OK, but 3 does not work. If I remove the step 2, 3 is working.

I don't know if it is because I'm mixing Roslyn & DTE or if it's because step 2 generate new code in the solution and my cached context becomes invalid.

```
// Add the resource to the Resources.resx file
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(resxPath);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode($"//data[@name='{resourceIndentifierName}']");
if (node != null) return;
XmlElement dataElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("data");

XmlAttribute nameAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
nameAtt.Value = resourceIndentifierName;
dataElement.Attributes.Append(nameAtt);

XmlAttribute spaceAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("space", "xml");
spaceAtt.Value = "preserve";
dataElement.Attributes.Append(spaceAtt);

XmlElement valueElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("value");
valueElement.InnerText = value;
dataElement.AppendChild(valueElement);

XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//root");
Debug.Assert(rootNode != null, "rootNode != null");
rootNode.AppendChild(dataElement);
xmlDoc.Save(resxPath);

// Update the Resources.Designer.cs file
var dte = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE));
ProjectItem item = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(resxPath);
((VSProjectItem) item.Object)?.RunCustomTool();

// Replace the node
SyntaxNode oldRoot = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken)
  .ConfigureAwait(false);
SyntaxNode newRoot = oldRoot.ReplaceNode(oldNode, newNode);
return context.Document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
```

Comment: What's `newNode`?

Comment: `newNode` is a `QualifiedName`: Properties.Resources.MyResource

Comment: What exactly happens? But you can't do this; code actions must be pure functions.  For example, what about the hover preview?

Comment: I've disabled the preview for now (http://stackoverflow.com/q/37435740/200443)

Comment: At first run, the resource is added to the .resx file, but nothing change in the code. At second run, the resource exists, so the .resx is left untouched and the code is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's because step 2 generate new code in the solution and my cached context becomes invalid

This is what is happening. When you call `RunCustomTool` the visual studio file watcher api tells roslyn that the files have been updated and roslyn generates a new set of solution snapshots.  When you attempt to apply your codefix, roslyn looks at the solution snapshot that your codefix came from, sees that it does not match the current snapshot, and fails to apply it.

Comment: I've implemented `GetChangedSolutionAsync` instead of  `GetChangedDocumentAsync` and I'm updating now the .Designer.cs with Roslyn instead of doing it with `RunCustomTool`. And it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Finally it does not work because there is a conflict between my refactoring and the **ResXFileCodeGenerator**. Each time I modify the .resx, the .Designer.cs is updated by the **ResXFileCodeGenerator** and my snapshot becomes invalid. And if I disable the **ResXFileCodeGenerator**, the .Designer.cs disappear from the solution. I'm going to make it a standard VS command.